# SQLCMD Syntax error when running script that runs fine in management studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

When I run the this `select '$(''test'')'` in SQL Management Studio 2008 it returns `$('test')`

When I run `sqlcmd -S SERVER -E -d DATABASE -q "select $(''test'')"` on the command line it returns `Sqlcmd: Error: Syntax error at line 1 near command '''.`

If I remove the dollar sign it works.  Is the "$" a special character?

Is this a sqlcmd bug?  How can I change the script to get the desired result.

Comment: I am still confused, with @KM, about why you’re sending `SELECT $(''test'')` to SQL Server from `sqlcmd` whereas you’re sending `SELECT '$(''test'')'` from SSMS.

Comment: I'm not sure why the 2 statements are different in that way.  This was legacy code that was sending javascript from a table through a query.  I needed to be able to create the database from scripts on the command line and was running into issues with sqlcmd variables.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, `$(id)` has special semantics in SQLCMD: it is a variable substitution. You can run commands like:

```
sqlcmd /E /S . /v variable=MyTable /Q "select * from $(variable)"
```

and this will select from MyTable. As you guess, the `/v` is the switch to define a variable. SSMS on the other hand does not, by default, interpret the SQL for variable substitution. SSMS *can* be made to do this, by checking the option 'Open query widows in SQLCMD mode'.

For mode details see [Using sqlcmd with Scripting Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, thats what I need to know.  The -x switch disables variables, so this works: sqlcmd -S SERVER -E -d DATABASE -x -q "select $(''test'')"

Comment: Thank you.  I needed to know how to disable variables using the -x parameter.  I was getting an error on a giant copy, and couldn't find the reason why until now.

Comment: @Brain2000 if you have questions, post a question, not a comment.

Comment: @RemusRusanu My question was the same as Troy's.  I was thanking Troy for including how to disable variable substitution with the -x parameter, because that was the answer I needed.

Answer (score 0):

the command you are trying to run:

```
select $('test')
```

is not valid. As you note, when you remove the "$" it works:

```
select ('test')
```

I'm not sure what you are really trying to do, you have three `"` double quote characters, you could try using this command:

```
select '$(test)'
```

which would be:

```
sqlcmd -S SERVER -E -d DATABASE -q "select ''$(test)''"
```